# How to size Bootstrap 5 card with different size image responsively?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have four images with different sizes and are put in 4 cards in a row. All images have different heights and the cards look not tidy. I wonder if there is any way to fix this since I want it to be responsive. I have added this code below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I used only basic Bootstrap 5 cards template without any css for now. The image looks below.
[image]

This is the code I mentioned.

```
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/english.jpg" class="d-block w-100"
                    style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px; height: auto;" alt="english">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Best English class ever</h5>
                    <p>Won't regret to join this class</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to make the card to be tidy (ie. all images have same height) responsively. I can achieve either one only for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try focuspoint, give an image default hight and set the position of the image.

https://github.com/jonom/jquery-focuspoint